# iOS Application with multiple scenes using Sprite Kit and UIKit combined

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, uikit

I am developing iOS application in which Main Menu will be in SpriteKit and will have the following 4 scenes:

1. Scene A - developed using SpriteKit
2. Scene B - developed using UIKit
3. Scene C - developed using UIKit
4. Scene D - developed using SpriteKit

Since Main Scene or Game Scene is in SpriteKit, would there be any issues by implementing some scenes in UIKit? The scene transition between SpriteKit and UIViewControllers is possible and it works.

Comment: Many problems. UIKit items are added to the view, SpriteKit is added to scene. When switching scene, objects on the view remain (as they are added to the view, which presents the scene), but objects on the scene move with their scene. You should avoid using both if you can, as this can be very difficult to work with

Comment: As a side note, why do you want to use both SpriteKit and UIKit in your project?

Comment: It's a game. At the scene that I need to do drawing I prefer to use UIKit but in the scenes with actions and movements I prefer to use SpriteKit. Do I make sense?

Comment: ok your problem is calling them Scenes,  you do not want 4 scenes you want views,  Make 4 view controllers within your story board, and you can use your segue to do all the transitions you want

Comment: Think of UIView as Legos, and Sprite Kit as Knex.  Normally these 2 do not play at all together, but if you have a special lego block that connects to a Knex piece,  then you have a way to join the 2 sets of toys.  SKView is this special block.

Comment: Knight0fDragon, I'm doing everything pro-grammatically in SpriteKit and almost everything in UIKit. Are you saying to have 4 UIViewControllers, one for each scene? I have for my SpriteKit UIViewController and GameScene, and this is Main Menu. From this menu transitions happen to other scenes, either SpriteKit or UIKit scene, all programmatically.

Comment: @bihmaster, then yes, programmatically make 4 view controllers, or technically 3 because you can get away with using the view controller to specify which scene to load via the segue

Comment: @bihmaster,  I would recommend getting used to using the UIKit and SpriteKit builders/designers.  It makes life a lot easier, and you keep your design separated from your logic, which means less lines of code to have to write/read through

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, thanks for your further suggestions. Yes, I am making 30 view controllers where 29 of them are subclass of the first controller for my UIKit scenes. I did same for my SpriteKit scenes. Since I keep them unique from each other, working programmatically in most cases works just fine, without any problems. It some point I will post my answer with drawing.

Comment: please do not call them UIKit scenes and SpriteKit scenes, you may confuse others who may look at this question looking for help.  UIKit involves `UIView`s,  SpriteKit involves `SKScene`s, SceneKit uses `SCNScene`s

Comment: Agree, for UIKit UIViews and for SprtieKit SKScene. Thanks.